# WordPress: Images classified as unattached but they are uploaded to posts

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress, when an image is assigned as a featured image to a post, and then that post is deleted, it becomes an unattached image. It remains unattached even if it's used again in a new post.

This is problematic in my site's workflow. I wrote a script to remove unattached images (to save server space), but it gets rid of images that technically are uploaded to posts, but listed as unattached.

Is there a way to programmatically loop through all unattached media and assign their post_parent to the post they are actually uploaded to? That way they would no longer appear to be unattached.

Comment: The short answer is probably no, or at least not easily. The concept of “attached” is something that [core has been considering getting rid of](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6820) for a while now because it is vague and misunderstood. I’d recommend looking into a plugin such as [Media Cleaner](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/). The alternative is to get the image’s local path and search the post and post meta tables, making sure to maybe unserialize content as needed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas What I ended up doing was the reverse - searching through all posts, getting the feature image ID, and then determining if that image's post_parent matches the current post ID. However, I ended up finding something even more strange...two references to the same image. One with a url like ?attachment=1234, the other with more of a regular permalink looking structure. I'm pretty sure if I delete the one that's classified as unattached, it will mess up the actual attachment belonging to the post since both use the same file. Using WP All Import, maybe that's causing an issue...?